# How to update Table rows based on ID with JSON data received from AJAX response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I have a json response object which I need to update table rows having row with ids and td with ids from jquery so that onload of table all values are being updated with json object whenever i call the ajax function. please help me out  i am adding the code here. any help will be appreciable.....regards

AJAX :

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: URI_PREFIX+'/getDetails',
        data: JSON.stringify({devId}),
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
       }).done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

                  if(jqXHR.status==206){
                   alert("Invalid Username or Password");
                  }
                  else if(jqXHR.status==412){
                   alert("Your Acount is not activated");
                  }
                  else if(jqXHR.status==200){
                      var newData = data.masters;

                      $.each(newData, function(i, item) {

                          $('#branch2 td').
                            var $tr = $('<tr>').append(
                                $('<td>').text(item.rank),
                                $('<td>').text(item.content),
                                $('<td>').text(item.UID)
                            ); //.appendTo('#records_table');
                            console.log($tr.wrap('<p>').html());
                        });


                  }

                 });
```

Table :

```
<table class="table table-bordered"
                                style="width: 100%; margin-top: 20px;" id="descTable">
                        <thead style="text-align: center;">
                            <tr>
                                <th class="color"></th>
                                <th class="color">Amp</th>
                                <th class="color">Volt</th>
                                <th class="color">PF</th>
                                <th class="color">Watt</th>
                                <th class="color">Kwh</th>
                                <th class="color">Lrh</th>
                                <th class="color">Temp1</th>
                                <th class="color">Temp2</th>
                            </tr>
                                </thead>
<tbody style="text-align: center;" class="omega">

                            <tr class="color1" id="branch1">
                                <td>Branch1 Real Values</td>
                                <td class="optAmp" style="font-family: 'calc'">ajax value</td>
                                <td class="optVolt" style="font-family: 'calc'">ajax value</td>
                                <td class="optPf" style="font-family: 'calc'">ajax value</td>
                                <td class="optWatt" style="font-family: 'calc'">ajax value</td>
                                <td class="optKwh" style="font-family: 'calc'">ajax value</td>
                                <td class="optLhr" style="font-family: 'calc'">ajax value</td>
                                <td class="optTmp1" style="font-family: 'calc'">ajax value</td>
                                <td class="optTmp2" style="font-family: 'calc'">ajax value</td>
                            </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: I have to update  td values with my json data bsed on id selectors defined and i have there rows with tr id and branch1 branch2 and branch3 having same td ids .... need to populate the data in JSON object i have all the values for all branch tr....

Comment: That's the task. What problem is causing to you? Where is that you're failing?

Comment: I failed to get td selector inside tr so that i can replace the value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access the td with `class="optAmp"` inside the tr (let's say the one with `id="brach1"` for example), you can use `$('tr#branch1 td.optAmp')`.

So to change it's value, you in the each function could do:

```
$('tr#branch1 td.optAmp').text(item.optAmp); // I assume your item object has that property
$('tr#branch1 td.rank').text(item.rank);
// and on ...
```

Comment: @VickySinghGill You're welcome! Glad that helped! :)